# Javascript fetch Jquery datepicker value and convert to integer for calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-arithmetic

I am having the following problem 
I have 2 inputs with id 'line_start_time' and id 'line_end_time', and with datepicker in them. 
And I need to get the values from the 2 inputs, and then convert them into integer, so I can use the 2 integers and do further calculations.

```
startTime = $("#line_start_time").val()
endTime = $("#line_end_time").val()
```

An sample output I get for startTime is April 2, 2014 12:00 AM or April 2, 2014. Could people teach me how to convert it into integers please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the date information and converting them to integers, you could

1. Get a JavaScript *Date* instance using `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );`
2. Use the returned object's methods to get the required values.

Further information:

- For information about JavaScript's *Date* object, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
- Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martwig/PDu6w/).

**Edit**

I've just updated the jsFiddle a bit. Now it calculates the difference between two selected dates in days. See http://jsfiddle.net/martwig/PDu6w/3/.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will give you the Unix timestamp you're looking for.

```
function getUnixTimeFromString(string) {

time = new Date(string);
unixTime = time.getTime()/1000; 
    return unixTime;

}
```

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/P9YWd/