# Pass the results of a date selected via Bootstraps datepicker, and put it in a URL link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, calendar

I am working on a hotel site that uses the Bootstrap datepicker to have the user select their 'Check In' and 'Check Out' dates.  Both of those dates should be passed to a 'booking' website when a button is clicked.

For example, if the user selects the dates for Check In as: 28 November, 2020, and the Check Out as: 29 December, 2020, then I need to get both of those dates into the url using this format:

[bookingsite.com/hotelname?checkInDate=2020-11-28&checkOutDate=2020-12-29](https://bookingsite.com/hotelname?checkInDate=2020-11-28&checkOutDate=2020-12-29)

I am hoping I can do this via some JavaScript, but I can't figure out how to access the dates that were picked using datepicker.  And, as the format of the datepicker results are not in the format that the URL allows, then I guess I will have to get the variables of each part of the date (ie: the day, the month and the year) separately.

**Here is the tricky part.**  Unfortunately, it appears that this site has an ***older version of Bootstrap or datepicker***, and it isn't picking up any scripting I added on the page for the datepicker to set formatting (doesn't use standard variables that the newer datepicker scripts use).  Here is an example of a script that would normally work for newer datepickers, but doesn't for mine.  (Example provided by Chiperific in answer to another post of mine):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: {
        // We're sending an object, not a string
        toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
            // this gets messy, sorry
            var d = new Date(date);
            var year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);
            var month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(d);
            var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d);
            return day + " " + month + ", " + year;
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of what I think is the normal datepicker.js, this is the one that is being used on this site (Note: I have already adjusted it to suit my needs on this site):

```
var Datepicker = function () {

  return {
    
    //Datepickers
    initDatepicker: function () {
        // Regular datepicker
        $('#date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
        });
        
        // Date range
        $('#start').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            minDate: 'TODAY()',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $('#finish').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
        
        // Inline datepicker
        $('#inline').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
        });
        
        // Inline date range
        $('#inline-start').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#inline-finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $('#inline-finish').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $('#inline-start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            }
        });
    }

  };
}();
```

Here is the HTML code to display the calendar fields:

```
    <form action="#" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">
        <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
            <section class="col-md-6">
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="start" id="start" placeholder="Check In Date" class="datepicker">
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col-md-6">
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="finish" id="finish" placeholder="Check out Date" class="datepicker">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
</form>
```

And here is the button code:

```
    <div class="call-action-v1-in inner-btn page-scroll" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <a href="https://www.bookingsite.com/hotelname?checkInDate=2020-11-28&checkOutDate=2020-12-29" target="_blank" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-dark btn-u-block">RESERVE A ROOM TODAY</a>
</div>
```

For the moment, I have manually placed in the dates in the above link for the check-in/check-out fields.  This is is obviously where I need to have some script to pull in the date parameters that are provided by the datepicker.

So instead of this section: `?checkInDate=2020-11-28&checkOutDate=2020-12-29`,it should have something like this: `?<script>document.write(Date.parse(startDate), Date.parse(endDate));</script>`

With the above startDate & endDate variables being created elsewhere.

Can anyone help me figure out what I can add to my version of the datepicker.js (as shown above), that will allow me to put the selected date into a passable variable to use in creating the URL?  (Probably needing to have day, month and year as individual variables for both start & finish dates, as the dateformat for calendar display is "**dd MMM, yyyy**", and the URL format needs it to be "**yyyy-mm-dd**"

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to pass the dates selected into a link.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767162/javascript-fetch-jquery-datepicker-value-and-convert-to-integer-for-calculation/23767785#23767785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Goal:** formulate this string:

```
https://www.bookingsite.com/hotelname?checkInDate=2020-11-28&checkOutDate=2020-12-29
```

I suggest updating the HREF of the link with JS every time a `.datpicker` is changed.
Adding an ID to the link will help us out:

```html
<a id="some_id" href="https://www.bookingsite.com/hotelname?checkInDate=2020-11-28&checkOutDate=2020-12-29" target="_blank" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-dark btn-u-block">RESERVE A ROOM TODAY</a>
```

## Rewrite:

Based on your fiddle, here is my suggested script ([my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aucynksp/2/)):

```js
Datepicker = function Datepicker() {
  reformatDate = function reformatDate(date) {
    // var d = new Date(date);
    let year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(date);
    let month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(date);
    let day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(date);
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  };

  rebuildHref = function rebuildHref() {
    let urlBase = 'https://www.bookingsite.com/hotelname?checkInDate='
    // $().datepicker('getDate') returns a Date Object!
    let checkInDate = $('#start').datepicker('getDate');
    let checkOutDate = $('#finish').datepicker('getDate');

    // CONDITION: catch scenario where Check In Date comes after Check Out Date
    // only proceed if dateCheckIn is < dateCheckOut
    if (checkInDate < checkOutDate) {
      let formattedInDate = reformatDate(checkInDate);
      let formattedOutDate = reformatDate(checkOutDate);
      let newUrl = urlBase + formattedInDate + "&checkOutDate=" + formattedOutDate;
      window.alert(newUrl);
      $('a#bookdates').removeClass('disabled').attr('href', newUrl);
      $('p#link_error').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('p#link_error').removeClass('hidden');
      $('a#bookdates').addClass('disabled').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    }
  };

  return { 
    //Datepickers
    initDatepicker: function initDatepicker() {
      // Regular datepicker
      $('#date').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
          prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
          nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
      });
            
      // Date range
      $('#start').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd M, yy',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
        minDate: 'TODAY()',
        onSelect: function( selectedDate )
        {
          $('#finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);       
          rebuildHref();
        }
      });

      $('#finish').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd M, yy',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
        onSelect: function( selectedDate )
        {
          // Limiting the start date is probably not beneficial:
          // Scenario: I select a start date within the 1st week of October,
          //           then I select an end date within the 1st week of October,
          //           then I realize I should have selected November dates
          //           but when I go back to select a new start date, I'm locked out of
          //           selecting any dates past the first week of October
          //           IF #start's selectedDate HAS to be before #end's selectedDate,
          //           let's handle that a different way. See the new If statement in rebuildHref();
          // $('#start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);          
          rebuildHref();
        }
      });
            
      // Inline datepicker
      $('#inline').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
          prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
          nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
      });
      
      // Inline date range
      $('#inline-start').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
          prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
          nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
          onSelect: function( selectedDate )
          {
              $('#inline-finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
          }
      });
      $('#inline-finish').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy',
          prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
          nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
          onSelect: function( selectedDate )
          {
            // probably don't want this one either
            // $('#inline-start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
          }
      });
    }
  }
}();
```

### Major things I changed:

```js
checkInDate = $('#start').datepicker('selectedDate');
checkOutDate = $('#finish').datepicker('selectedDate');
```

Turns out there's no 'selectedDate' attribute, we needed 'getDate':

```js
checkInDate = $('#start').datepicker('getDate');
checkOutDate = $('#finish').datepicker('getDate');
```

**Figuring out what methods are available on `$().datepicker()` seems to be your biggest hold-up.**
You are using JQuery 1.10.4, so I found the docs specific to that version:
https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/datepicker

That's where you'll find the available methods, like [`getDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/datepicker/#method-getDate)

And, good news, `$().datepicker('getDate')` returns a Date Object!

So we don't need the first line of `reformatDate()` to make a new Date:

```js
var reformatDate = function(date) {
  // No longer need this line:
  // var d = new Date(date);
  ...
};
```

I also don't know why you had everything nested inside a return. I'm not a Javascript guru, so maybe you know something I don't. But I moved the reusable functions outside of the `return` call and only left the `initDatepicker` stuff inside the `return`.

### Minor things I changed:

I made sure all variables were preceded by `let` and fixed a few missing `;`.

I'm also suggesting a change to the `#start` field's `onSelect` function. I don't think you really want to limit the values of the Start date.

```js
$('#finish').datepicker({
  ...
  onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
   // See my long comment in the full code example, but I don't think you want to do this.
   // $('#start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
  }
});
```

**Here's why:**

1. I select a start date within the 1st week of October,
2. Then I select an end date within the 1st week of October,
3. Then I realize I should have selected November dates
4. But when I go back to select a new start date, I'm locked out of selecting any dates past the first week of October

Because I don't think you should restrict the start date, we could have a situation where the End date comes before the Start date, so we need a conditional to check for that before we build the link:

```js
rebuildHref = function rebuildHref() {
    ...
    // CONDITION: catch scenario where Check In Date comes after Check Out Date
    // only proceed if dateCheckIn is < dateCheckOut
    if (checkInDate < checkOutDate) {
      // Good dates
    } else {
      // Bad dates
    }
  };
```

And I think the link should be disabled until you have 2 good dates, so I added some CSS:

```css
/* disable the link with CSS */
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none; 
  cursor: default; 
}
```

I also added the `.disabled` class to the link's HTML so it's there on page load when the form fields are blank.
As a 2nd line of safety against bad link clicking, I set the link up like this:

```html
<a id="bookdates" href="javascript:void(0)" ... /a>
```

The `javascript:void(0)` means that even if the user manages to click the link, it won't do anything.
This is also a great way to tell if your script works, because

You'll see calls like `$('a#bookdates').addClass('disabled');` or `$('a#bookdates').removeClass('disabled');` to handle enabling / disabling the link based upon our conditional.

The same is true for a `<p>` I added below the button to display a warning as to why the link is un-clickable. I gave it the class of "hidden" to start off with and I remove or add that class based upon the conditional.

Comment: Thanks Chiperific, I really appreciate all your valuable help.  However, I am having problems implementing your suggestions.  First I need to note that I am using the $start and $finish scripts (not $inline-start and $inline-finish).  I adjusted your code accordingly, but it appears to get stuck on the "checkInDate" line, and doesn't execute the reformatDate function.  I also couldn't figure out what I needed to change on the actual a href link in the html code to pull in the newUrl.

Comment: I have created a Fiddle setup with all my specific javascripts, css and html code here: https://jsfiddle.net/SunnyOz/jm2hdx96/5/.  You will note when you run it that I have added some alerts to debug it.  They are placed to indicate if the coding at each section is actually accessed.  You can change it as you wish.  (The datepicker.js is displayed in the JS box, to make it easier to change during testing.).

Comment: Oops, I had left off some quote marks.. use this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/SunnyOz/jm2hdx96/7/

Comment: @SunnyOz, I much appreciate the fiddle, it helped me give you a much better answer. See the re-written answer above.

Comment: OMG @Chiperific.  You truly went above and beyond, and it is very much appreciated.  I would give you a hundred upticks if I could.  Just to let you know what I have done differently:  I changed the month format to be numeric for the URL creation;  I took off the default href of javascript:void(0) and replaced it with the generic link to the booking page without dates (this is allowed on many other links on this site - they can select dates once they get to the booking site).

Comment: Thanks so much for the IF statement, and also the documentation for the older version of jQuery.  (I thought the issues I was having was with one of the scripts being an older version, but I wasn't sure which one.  Note: I inherited the datepicker.js, so I am not sure why they used the 'return' statement, so I just left it in.)  If you would like to see your work live, here is the site: https://www.citycentrebudgethotel.com.au/stage/default.asp.  Thanks again for all your hard work!